# Printing a function's local variable names and values

Tags: python, namespaces, decorator, python-decorators

To help me debug some of the code I write, I want to make a function decorator that prints off the name of a variable and its value as each variable is created or modified, essentially giving me a "play-by-play" view of what happens when I call the function.

The approach I had been using up until this point is simply adding a line like `print(foo)` wherever I wanted to see what was happening, but this is extremely time-consuming and makes my code messy to look at (possibly the epitome of un-Pythonicness).

Effectively what I want to do is have this:

```
@show_guts
def foo(a,b):
    biz = str(a)
    baz = str(b)
    return biz + baz

foo("banana","phone")
```

print something like this in the IDE:

```
biz = "banana"
baz = "phone"
bananaphone
```

My question is what `@show_guts` would look like.  I know it's possible to print only the values of `a` and `b` with a decorator like

```
def print_args(function):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print("Arguments:",args)
        print("Keyword Arguments:",kwargs)
        return function(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

which gives me

```
Arguments: ('banana', 'phone')
Keyword Arguments: {}
'bananaphone'
```

but I'm totally stumped as to how to print the local variable names as well as their values.  Not to mention do it in a "neat" way.

Comment: Instead of writing a complex decorator, consider using the [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#pdb) module. You can pause execution of your program using `pdb.set_trace`, view the contents of variables, and step through lines of code one at a time, giving you a comprehensive "play by play" view.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot do this without enabling tracing; this will hurt performance. Function locals are constructed when the function is called, and cleaned up when it returns, so there is no other way to access those locals from a decorator.

You can insert a trace function using [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace), then respond to the events the Python interpreter sends that function. What we want to do is trace *just* the decorated function, and record the locals when the function returns:

```
import sys
import threading

def show_guts(f):
    sentinel = object()
    gutsdata = threading.local()
    gutsdata.captured_locals = None
    gutsdata.tracing = False

    def trace_locals(frame, event, arg):
        if event.startswith('c_'):  # C code traces, no new hook
            return 
        if event == 'call':  # start tracing only the first call
            if gutsdata.tracing:
                return None
            gutsdata.tracing = True
            return trace_locals
        if event == 'line':  # continue tracing
            return trace_locals

        # event is either exception or return, capture locals, end tracing
        gutsdata.captured_locals = frame.f_locals.copy()
        return None

    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # preserve existing tracer, start our trace
        old_trace = sys.gettrace()
        sys.settrace(trace_locals)

        retval = sentinel
        try:
            retval = f(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            # reinstate existing tracer, report, clean up
            sys.settrace(old_trace)
            for key, val in gutsdata.captured_locals.items():
                print '{}: {!r}'.format(key, val)
            if retval is not sentinel:
                print 'Returned: {!r}'.format(retval)
            gutsdata.captured_locals = None
            gutsdata.tracing = False

        return retval

    return wrapper
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> @show_guts
... def foo(a,b):
...     biz = str(a)
...     baz = str(b)
...     return biz + baz
... 
>>> result = foo("banana","phone")
a: 'banana'
biz: 'banana'
b: 'phone'
baz: 'phone'
Returned: 'bananaphone'
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty advanced for me!  Assuming that I wasn't worried about performance, would this method work for tracing each local variable as it's constructed?  Or would I have to go about it differently?

Comment: @PolskiPhysics: You can certainly trace how locals are changing, yes. You'd have to see how `frame.f_locals` changed with each `line` event call; see what keys are added and removed, and what values have changed. Be careful, detecting what values have changed can get hairy rather quickly.

Answer (score 4):

### In the spirit of debugging, I present my hax:

```
import re
import inspect

assignment_regex = re.compile(r'(\s*)([\w\d_]+)\s*=\s*[\w\d+]')

def show_guts(fn):
    source = inspect.getsource(fn)
    lines = []
    for line in source.split('\n'):
        if 'show_guts' in line:
            continue
        lines.append(line)
        if 'def' in line:
            # kwargs will match the regex
            continue
        search = assignment_regex.search(line)
        try:
            groups = search.groups()
            leading_whitespace = groups[0]
            variable_name = groups[1]
            lines.append(leading_whitespace + 'print "Assigning {0} =", {0}'.format(variable_name))
        except AttributeError:  # no match
            pass
    new_source = '\n'.join(lines)
    namespace = {}
    exec new_source in namespace
    fn = namespace[fn.__name__]

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        arg_string = ', '.join(map(str, args))
        kwarg_string = ', '.join(key + '=' + str(value) for key, value in kwargs.iteritems())
        print "Calling", fn.__name__ + '(' + ', '.join((arg_string, kwarg_string)) + ')'
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Basically, this is automatically doing what you were doing. It gets the source for the function passed in, loop over each line in the source and for each assignment statement, create a new print statement and append it to the source body. The new source is compiled and the function is replaced with the newly compiled function. Then to get the `*args` and `**kwargs`, I create the normal decorator wrapper function and throw in some nice print statements. That part could probably be a little better with some help from the `inspect` module, but whatevs.

#### foo() -> foo() with print statements

```
# This...
@show_guts
def complicated(a, b, keyword=6):
    bar = str(a)
    baz = str(b)
    if a == b:
        if keyword != 6:
            keyword = a
    else:
        keyword = b
    return bar + baz

# becomes this
def complicated(a, b, keyword=6):
    bar = str(a)
    print "Assigning bar =", bar
    baz = str(b)
    print "Assigning baz =", baz
    if a == b:
        if keyword != 6:
            keyword = a
            print "Assigning keyword =", keyword
    else:
        keyword = b
        print "Assigning keyword =", keyword
    return bar + baz
```

#### Usage

```
@show_guts
def foo(a, b):
    bar = str(a)
    baz = str(b)
    return bar + baz


@show_guts
def complicated(a, b, keyword=6):
    bar = str(a)
    baz = str(b)
    if a == b:
        if keyword != 6:
            keyword = a
    else:
        keyword = b
    return bar + baz


foo(1, 2)
complicated(3, 4)
complicated(3, 3)
complicated(3, 3, keyword=123)
```

#### Output

```
Calling foo(1, 2, )
Assigning bar = 1
Assigning baz = 2
Calling complicated(3, 4, )
Assigning bar = 3
Assigning baz = 4
Assigning keyword = 4
Calling complicated(3, 3, )
Assigning bar = 3
Assigning baz = 3
Calling complicated(3, 3, keyword=123)
Assigning bar = 3
Assigning baz = 3
Assigning keyword = 3
```

There are probably some corner cases that I'm missing with the regex, but this will get you close.